# Return Value from JOptionPane indicating the button selected

Tags: java, switch-statement, joptionpane

I have made an option panel, but I can't get the buttons to actually do as they are meant to.
I have tried to make action an int which is connected to the panel, but that doesn't work.

```
Object[] choices = null;
    Object[] options = { "Criticals", "Pure Damage", "Heal 300 points", "Flee" };
    JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "What will you do?", "action",
            JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
            null, options, options[0]);

    switch (action)
    {
    case 0: 
        int Criticals = (int) (Math.random()*500);
        Criticals++;
        caitlyn.enemyhealth = (caitlyn.enemyhealth-Criticals);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Caitlyn now has" +" " + caitlyn.enemyhealth + "HP left");
        break;
    case 1:
        int PureDamage = (int) (Math.random()*300);
        PureDamage++;
        caitlyn.enemyhealth = (caitlyn.enemyhealth-PureDamage);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Caitlyn now has" + " " + caitlyn.enemyhealth + "HP left");
        break;
    case 2:
        int heal = 300;
        heal++;
        newchamp.health = (newchamp.health+heal);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "You now have"+ " " + newchamp.health + "HP points!");
        break;
```

also, I don't know how I would make it so that the damage or the heal that has been done, is saved and will stay at that level for the next attack, instead of return to default.

Comment: What is the variable action? Where is it defined?

Comment: at the very top of my complete code:


private static int action;

Comment: You are not getting the return value of `showConfirmDialog()` and assigning it to the `action`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need:

```
    int action = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "What will you do?", "action",
        JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
        null, options, options[0]);
```

You're ignoring the return value of the method, which tells you which button is pressed.