# Return the value from JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I have made a `JOptionPane` which contains a `JPanel`. The panel contains one button and one Jtable.

```
JPanel p = atomicAttack.getPanel(); //make the panel and return it
JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, p,"Atomic Attacks", 
            JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, 
            null, new Object[]{}, null);
```

and inside the JButton i have:

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    selectedId=jTable1.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString();
}
```

I need to when the user clicks on the button, the **JOption get closed** and the `selectedId` **get return from the JOptionPane**?

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003170/return-value-from-joptionpane-indicating-the-button-selected), but it is not exactly what i am looking for. 
**Because the button does not return the value for me.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Focus on the models and things will be easier.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
    tableModel.addColumn("Selection", new Object[] { "A", "B", "C" });

    JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
    ListSelectionModel selectionModel = table.getSelectionModel();

    JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    p.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, p, "Atomic Attacks", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    if (JOptionPane.OK_OPTION == option) {
        printSelection(selectionModel, tableModel);
    } else {
        selectionModel.clearSelection();
    }

}

private static void printSelection(ListSelectionModel selectionModel, TableModel tableModel) {
    for (int i = selectionModel.getMinSelectionIndex(); i <= selectionModel.getMaxSelectionIndex(); i++) {
        if (selectionModel.isSelectedIndex(i)) {
            Object selectedValue = tableModel.getValueAt(i, 0);
            System.out.println(selectedValue);
        }
    }
}
```

If you now select multiple rows

[image: Table model selection in JOptionPane]

and press the ok button the result will be

```
A
C
```

If you want a single selection you can just set

```
ListSelectionModel selectionModel = table.getSelectionModel();      
selectionModel.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
```

Comment: If i get u correctly, u meant i should remove that jButton in the panel, and use JoptionPane buttons. True?

Comment: You don't need to remove it. The example above will also work if you close the option pane with your button. I just used the default option pane buttons to make things for my example a bit easier and the default buttons are language aware out of the box.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't make sense to have 2 buttons with same functionalities

Comment: That's true. I would go the one or the other way.